# Joining python list tuple elements based on adjacent tuple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've a list which is like :

```
x = [(0, 'Add:'), (1, 'Net'), (2, 'Profit'), (4, 'Less:'), (5, 'Dep')]
```

I want to join second tuple elements values for adjacent first tuple elements like tuples with first element 0, 1, 2 should be joined into a new string "Add: Net Profit" and tuples with first element 4, 5 should be joined into a new string "Less: Dep". I've tried :

```
for i in range(len(x) -1):
    if x[i+1][0] - x[i][0] == 1:
         temp_str = x[i][1] + " " + x[i+1][1]
```

It gives output as :

```
Add: Net
Net Profit
Less: Dep
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that that is the code you are using?  `x[i+1][0] - x[i][0]` is going to: 1) raise `KeyError` when an index is missing and 2) is going to subtract the string `"N"` from the string `"A"` which is an other `TypeError`.

Comment: What does "adjacent" mean here?

Comment: The code you have would only return that output if `x = [[0, 'Add:'], [1, 'Net'], [2, 'Profit'], [4, 'Less:'], [5, 'Dep']]` and you printed temp string out each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most elegant Python code ever, but it is a good starting point.

```
x = {0: 'Add:', 1: 'Net', 2: 'Profit', 4: 'Less:', 5: 'Dep'}

keys = sorted(x)

strings = []
temp=x[keys[0]]
for i, j in zip(keys, keys[1:]):
  if j-i==1:
    temp += ' ' + x[j]
  else:
    strings.append(temp)
    temp=x[j]
strings.append(temp)

print(strings)  # ['Add: Net Profit', 'Less: Dep']
```

Answer (score 2):

You should divide your problem in subproblems. You want to combine groups of words, so you need the words in a list and use `join` on them.
You get groups with the `groupby`-function, for which you need a common criteria, e.g. the difference between the position in the list and the number in the tuple.

```
from itertools import groupby

x = [(0, 'Add:'), (1, 'Net'), (2, 'Profit'), (4, 'Less:'), (5, 'Dep')]
for _, group in groupby(enumerate(x), lambda a:a[1][0] - a[0]):
    words = [text for _, (_,text) in group] # extract words from data structure
    print(' '.join(words))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to first get the keys of the dictionary and sort them, then start iterating over the keys until you find a gap, and after that you can join all the values:

```
sorted_keys = sorted(x.keys())
start_index = 0
last_key = sorted_keys[0]
results = []
for i, cur_key in enumerate(sorted_keys):
    if cur_key - last_key > 1:
        # a gap has ended.
        results.append(' '.join(x[k] for k in range(start_index, i)))
        start_index = i
    last_key = cur_key
if start_index != i:
    results.append(' '.join(x[k] for k in range(start_index, i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the list of tuples you could use:

```
x = [(0, 'Add:'), (1, 'Net'), (2, 'Profit'), (4, 'Less:'), (5, 'Dep')]

indices = sorted([x[i][0] for i in range(len(x))])

out = [[]]
pos = 0 
for i in range(len(x)):
    out[pos].append(x[i][1])
    if indices[i]+1 not in indices and indices[i] != max(indices):
        out.append([])
        pos += 1
out = [' '.join(i) for i in out ]

print(out)
```